# How to get ConnectionString from appsettings.json file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

the question is how to get the ConnectionString from appsetting.json file in ASP NET Core 3.1 application?
Here is the appsetings.json file

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "data source=exmaple;initial catalog=example;persist security info=True;user id=example;password=example"
}
```

In the example, all parameters are hidden behind the names example

In the Program.cs class, I include files

```
static void ConfigureAppConfiguration(WebHostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder config, string[] args)
{
    config
         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
         .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.ToLowerInvariant()}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
         .AddEnvironmentVariables()
         .AddCommandLine(args);
}
```

and when I try to get the connection string values in the Startup class, I get null

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connetctionString = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    ...
}
```

Why connection == null ?

Comment: where and how do you use this `ConfigureAppConfiguration`?

Comment: Since other answers  failed to sovle your issue, it may sound like a path issue. Check that the file is correctly copied in output directory (something like Debug/bin/ in debug mode). If not, open file's property and choose "Copy if newer" or "Copy always" on the Build Actions.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the previous answer, you could also use in the `Startup.cs` the method you did, so it would look in the following:

```cs
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
          Configuration = configuration;
    }
    
            
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    }
```

Also be aware that you do not need to specify the configuration files explicitly in the `Program.cs`. You also could use the [`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), which automatically adds the files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo:

startup:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connetctionString = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "data source=exmaple;initial catalog=example;persist security info=True;user id=example;password=example"
  }
}
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.ToLowerInvariant()}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables()
               .AddCommandLine(args);
            })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

And if you want to set configuration in program.cs,you can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0),and set it in `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)`.

Comment: Strange, but I still have null when debugging persists

Comment: Try to set configuration in program.cs as I updated in my answer,can it work?

Comment: `GetConnectionString` is an extension method for conveniently getting the connection string based on default (standard) names for the connection string settings, it's basically the same as `GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value` or simpler as `GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

But if your goal is to override the appsettings.json here is a little guide

The default order is 1) appsettings.json, 2) appsettings.{env}.json, 3) secrets.json, 4) environment variables, 5) console args. This means that anything you ovveride for example in num 2 has impact in number 1 etc. So your program is looking for settings in reverse order if there is any. If you want to change this order you can do the following:

In Program class inside CreateHostBuilder in .ConfigureAppConiguration

```
IHostEnvironment env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
builder.Sources.Clear();

//Now the first in order became the #2 of defaults
builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
 
if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
}
builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
builder.AddCommandLine(args);
```